# Mapbox incorrect LatLng list for two points

Tags: android, routes, mapbox

I have used [this documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/examples/directions/), `(-47.882645, -15.794082)` and `(-47.866611, -15.762604)` for destination and start points, what I get is totally incorrect LatLng response. The distance and response code (see logcat, please)are correct though. Any on that, please.

`04-10 18:29:46.813 23586-23586/ D/MapActivity: Response code: 200
04-10 18:29:46.814 23586-23586/ D/MapActivity: Distance: 107.0
04-10 18:29:46.824 23586-23586/ D/MapActivity: LatLng [latitude=404.13863, longitude=499.34955, altitude=0.0]
04-10 18:29:46.824 23586-23586/ D/MapActivity: LatLng [latitude=404.12946, longitude=499.34574, altitude=0.0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting your polyline to a linestring use precision 6 instead of OSRM_PRECISION_V5